# How to check values in a database Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am processing a Post request with Json data, how do I add them to the database, so that there is a check that finds out if there is already this user in the database or not, if not, then create a new row, if there is, then update messages for this user.

What I accept in the request: phone, message

I do not quite understand how to implement it.

UserController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {
        userRepo.save(requestUserDetails);
        return "The message delivered.";
    }
}
```

User

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ApiTable", schema = "TestApi")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String phone;
        private String message;


        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setLastName(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
```

UserRepo

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

KeyUser

```
public class KeyUser implements Serializable {
    private String phone;
    private  String message;
}
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need a relevant method in your repository, e.g `User findOneByPhone(String phone)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `userRepo.save(requestUserDetails)` already do it for you.

Look at the implementation of `save` method in `SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>` class from Spring.

**SimpleJpaRepository.java**

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>` implements the `JpaRepository<T, ID>`, which is inherited by `CrudRepository<T, ID>`.

This already check if the object already exists on the database. All you have to supply is your entity with the primary key populated.

If the primary key is not populated, then Spring can't check if the object exists. So a new row will be created.

If the object already exists, it will call `EntityManager.merge` if not, it will call `EntityManager.persist`.

Take a look:

```
User use = new User();
user.setId(1);
user.setPhone("123");
user.setMessage("Hello");

userRepository.save(user);
```

In this case, if the `User` with `id == 1` exists on the the database, it's information will be merged.

Now, if, for some reason, this don't fit for you, then you will have to do it manually, by searching for the user by it's ID and then applying some rule to it.

Something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User requestUserDetails) {
        User user = requestUserDetails;

        if(requestUserDetails.getId() != null) {
            Optional<User> userOpt = userRepo.findById(requestUserDetails.getId());
            if (userOpt.isPresent()) {
                user = userOpt.get();
                // the user exists... do something..
            }
        }

        // at the end, save the user anyway (event if it exists or not)
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "The message delivered.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to update the object you can use the `merge` method. If the object has the id attribute, use merge, else, save.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the other answer is more effective. I didn't quite understand what you wanted to say, but thank you very much for your interest.